# PHP/MySQL to calculate difference between items with same foreign key

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

I have one table `items` with columns `id`, `name` and one table `ratings` with `id`, `itemid`, `rating`. What I would like to do is return results where the difference between two ratings with the same `itemid` is the biggest, in descending order.

Comment: I would start by building test data.

Comment: Will there be only and exactly _two_ ratings per item?

Comment: I do have test data. I just don't have any idea on where to start and whether I can do this with the MySQL query or I have to loop through the results with PHP.

Comment: no, there can be more than two ratings, but I only need to calculate the biggest difference between the two most "extreme" ratings.

Comment: Great that you have test data would you like to post it here as text?

Answer (score 2):

You could subtract the maximum rating from the minimum rating, and order by that:

```
SELECT   i.*
FROM     items i
JOIN     (SELECT   itemid, MAX(rating) - MIN(rating) AS diff
          FROM     ratings
          GROUP BY itemid) r ON i.id = r.itemid
ORDER BY diff DESC
```

Comment: That seems like a great solution! The query doesn't seem to work as such, but I'm sure this is on the right track. I'll play around with it and report back here.

Comment: The query returns all rows from the table, could you check it? i'll be more than happy to accept your answer.